# Confidence intervals for partial ROC areas (spec 90-100%) using package pROC

Tags: r, roc

I have 4 different parameters (HRTT, MRWT, HRWT and RNFLT) and am plotting sensitivity versus specificity curves for each. I want to:

1. Find the partial area under the ROC curve (pAUC) for each parameter (for specificities in the range 90-100%) and the confidence interval around this pAUC for each parameter.
2. Compare the pAUCs to evaluate which pAUC is statistically highest.

For 1., I calculated the pAUC estimate for HRTT:

```
auc(rocHRTT, partial.auc=c(100, 90), partial.auc.focus="spec",percent=TRUE, partial.auc.correct=TRUE, ci=TRUE)
```

I then calculated the CI around this by:

```
ci.auc(rocHRTT, partial.auc=c(100, 90), partial.auc.focus="spec",percent=TRUE, partial.auc.correct=TRUE, ci=TRUE)
```

I then repeated this for MRWT, HRTW and RNFLT.

For some reason, the estimate of pAUC often lies outside the CI for pAUC and I can't figure out why. For instance, MRWT the pAUC is 71%, but the CI is 77-91%!

For 2., I know that the function `roc.test` can be used to compare 2 pAUCs, but how can I compare 4 areas to evaluate which is highest?

Comment: It would be better if your question included a minimal, sufficient [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). That will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Bootstrap has some assumptions, in particular it's going to behave funny with less than 10 observations. Difficult to know if that's your case.

Comment: Also if you have two questions, then please ask two separate questions (see your point 2).

Comment: Verify if `partial.auc=c(100, 90)` is the problem. Do the analysis whit total area.